# Is it possible to upgrade/replace built-in "contacts" aplication?

Tags: updates, builds

I was wondering if it is possible to build "Contacts" from [ASOP](https://source.android.com)/[Google](https://android.googlesource.com) sources, and then replace original -**single application**- provided by phone manufacturer? This concerns device without root.
I assume there are three cases here:

1. Heavily modified software like for example Samsung's phones
2. Phones with modified software but heavily based on ASOP (**my case**)
3. Phones with pure ASOP sources (not sure, Nexus'es?)

I wanted to ask if it is correct that in case:

1. it is nearly impossible without manufacturer signing key. One can install additional application to manage contacts but most likely cannot remove manufacturer's replacement.
2. it is nearly impossible as well (same case as above) - despite application source being available, it cannot be "upgraded"/"replaced" due to fact that it is not signed by manufacturer's key
3. Only case where this might be possible ?

Comment: Why take the complicated way? Simply install an alternative contacts app (see [Contact Managers and Dialers](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_dialer) for a list of possible candidates), and then disable the original one (if possible – it might be locked) or even completely remove it (requires root).

Comment: @Izzy, one of many reasons would be that this is purely open source application - with no advertisements, and known code. Or for example - to save space. I know it might seem complicated but it's a matter of one's priorities and preferences.

Comment: I'd say that's as with launchers: push your alternative app to `/system/apps`, check whether it works, then remove the original. Even when done with the AOSP one you prefer, that rules out "cases #1 & #2" (signature won't matter), and thus should work ;)